# How to get epoch time in momentjs after using utcoffset

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

```
const epoch = Date.UTC(2017,09,24)

const moment_epoch = moment.utc(epoch).utcOffset(5.5).valueOf()
```

Why do `epoch` and `moment_epoch` produce the same output when I am adding the offset?

How do I get the epoch time after adding the offset?

Comment: ["Epoch time" is a misnomer. Please stop using that terminology.](https://codeofmatt.com/2017/10/05/please-dont-call-it-epoch-time/) You mean a "Unix timestamp in milliseconds" - which are always in UTC. Adjusting the offset changes your local perspective - not the instant represented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the values, step by step, it becomes easier to understand what's happening:

- `Date.UTC(2017,09,24)` produces the timestamp equivalent to October 24<sup>th</sup> 2017, at midnight, in UTC (`1508803200000`).
- `moment.utc(epoch)` produces a date in UTC, equivalent to the millis value above:

  > Tue Oct 24 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000
- `moment.utc(epoch).utcOffset(5.5)` just converts the UTC date to `+05:30` offset:

  > Tue Oct 24 2017 05:30:00 GMT+0530

But both dates correspond to the same instant (midnight in UTC is the same as 5:30 AM in `+05:30` offset), so the millis value will be the same (both will be `1508803200000`).

---

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but anyway:

- if you want to **add** 5 hours and 30 minutes to the date, just do:

  ```
  moment.utc(epoch).add(5, 'h').add(30, 'm')
  ```

  Note that this doesn't change the offset. It just gets a date which is 5 hours and 30 minutes after the original one.
- if you want a date that correponds to midnight at `+05:30` offset, you can do:

  ```
  moment.utc(epoch).utcOffset(5.5, true)
  ```

  The second parameter [tells `momentjs` to preserve the same local date/time](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/), so instead of converting to date/time to the offset, it keeps the same values - in this case, it'll be midnight in `+05:30` offset:

  > Tue Oct 24 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530

---

Regarding [your jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/4q5xmke2/2/), I've just changed it a little bit to also print the offset:

```
moment.utc(1508803200000).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm Z") // 24/10/2017 00:00 +00:00
moment.utc(1508803200000).utcOffset(5.5).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm Z") // 24/10/2017 05:30 +05:30
moment.utc(1508803200000).utcOffset(5.5, true).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm Z") // 24/10/2017 00:00 +05:30
moment.utc(1508803200000).valueOf() // 1508803200000
moment.utc(1508803200000).utcOffset(5.5).valueOf() // 1508803200000
moment.utc(1508803200000).utcOffset(5.5, true).valueOf() // 1508783400000
```

The value `1508803200000` corresponds to both `2017-10-24T00:00:00Z` (midnight in UTC) and `2017-10-24T05:30+05:30` (5:30 AM in India).

The first line just gets this value in UTC, so the result is `24/10/2017 00:00 +00:00`.

The second line converts this same value to the corresponding local date/time in `+05:30` offset. This doesn't change the epoch value (it still corresponds to `1508803200000`). The result is the equivalent date/time in India, which is `24/10/2017 05:30 +05:30` (5:30 AM in offset `+05:30`, the equivalent of midnight in UTC - both represent the same instant, that's why the `valueOf()` is the same).

The third line (with `utcOffset(5.5, true)`) doesn't convert **midnight in UTC** to **5:30 AM in India**. Instead, it creates a date equivalent to **midnight in India**, that's why the result is `24/10/2017 00:00 +05:30`. And the `valueOf()` returns `1508783400000`, which is equivalent to both **midnight in India** and **23/10/2017 18:30 in UTC** (6:30 PM of the day before, that's why the value is lower than the original one).

Comment: Date.UTC(2017,09,24) and Date.UTC(2017,09,24, 05, 30) why this produce different epoch times?
moment.utc(1508803200000).utcOffset(5.5, true) subtract moment.utc(Date.UTC(2017,09,24)) results in a minus value, it should be a positive number, right?

Comment: @Nikhil What exactly are you trying to do? What should be the result?

Comment: @Nikhil `UTC(2017,09,24)` creates **October 24th 2017, at midnight in UTC**, while `UTC(2017,09,24,05,30)` creates **October 24th 2017, at 5:30 AM in UTC** (5 hours and 30 minutes **after** midnight in UTC). `utcOffset(5.5, true)` creates **midnight in +05:30 offset**, which corresponds to **October 23th 2017 (the day before) at 18:30 in UTC**, so it happened 5 hours and 30 minutes **before** midnight in UTC: https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/?qm=1&lid=100,30&h=100&date=2017-10-4&sln=18.5-19

Comment: @Nikhil I've updated the answer, see if it's more clear now

Comment: finally: `moment.utc(1508803200000).utcOffset(5.5, true).valueOf()` this makes me all day to find. Thanks man